# ajax download progress not working on firefox

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get download progress loader. This code works well on chrome  but doesn't on firefox. It pops up an alert showing download failed on firefox even if download continues, please how do i prevent the pop up?

This the html code

```
<form id="form-download" method="POST">
    <center>
        <div class="btn"> </div>
        </form>
    <!-- HTML !-->
    <button class="button" name="submit" id="btn" role="button">Download</button>
    <div class="loader" id="loader">
        <center>
            <img src='../img/Rolling.gif'class='loaderGif' style='margin-top: 10px' width='30' height='30' />
        </center>
    </div>
</center>
<div class="checkmate"></div>
<center>
    <?php  echo $msg; ?>
</center>
```

this is ajax code

```
<script>
$('#form-download').submit(function(e) {

//e.preventDefault();

let submit = "submit";

let loader = document.getElementById("loader")

$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'backup_log.php',
  data: {
    submit: submit
  },
  cache: true,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  beforeSend: function(e){
      
    loader.style.display = "block"
  },
 
  success: function(response){
    $(".loader").html('<div class="icon icon--order-success svg"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="72px" height="72px"><g fill="none" stroke="#8EC343" stroke-width="2"><circle cx="36" cy="36" r="35" style="stroke-dasharray:240px, 240px; stroke-dashoffset: 480px;"></circle>   <path d="M17.417,37.778l9.93,9.909l25.444-25.393" style="stroke-dasharray:50px, 50px; stroke-dashoffset: 0px;"></path></g></svg></div>');
       $("#btn").hide();
    console.log(response);
  },
  error: function(err){
    alert("your download failed");
  }
})
```

});

Comment: You aren't closing your `center` element correctly. The single line comment at `$(".loader").html("` should break the JS I think because of the multiple lines under that. Does developer console show any errors/warnings? Chrome might just be making better guesses at what you intended.

Comment: No errors in `Developer console`, and have removed the `single line comments` but still same error

Comment: Can you please update question code to show what you now have? Thanks.

Comment: please kindly check the code for the update. thanks

Comment: @-user3783243 please can you still help out?